# SQL Server 2008: populate a table with data from dynamic table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-table

I have two tables `Control1 (BatchID ,TableName)` , `Control2(BatchID, MemID)`  and there are additional tables that will be added to the database one by one. The format for the tablename is `ABC_date` for example `ABC_01032014` (dynamic)

Now this Table ABC_Date has one caolumn Called `MemID`.

`control1` and `control2` are empty tables and `abc_date` is populated with let's say `10 MemIds`.

So, I want to populate `control1` and `control2`. `Control1` would have a unique ID and 
`tableName = ABC_date` DONE

`control2` would have the same `BatchID` as `control1` and all `10 memIds` from `ABC_Date`. Please help with `control2`.

Now it should have all `10 memIDs` from `ABC_Date` and 1 same `batchID` from `control1`

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you want 10 rows in control 2 or just one with the MemIDs separated by a comma but I'm assuming you want 10 registers

you could use a cursor to do the job for you

```
Declare @BatchID
Declare @MemIdFetch

Set @BatchID = Select distinct BatchID from control1

--Declaration of the cursor
Declare CursorABC cursor for select MemID from ABC_date where BatchID = @BatchID

--Fetching the cursor
Fetch CursorABC into @MemIdFetch 

--Loop for the cursor 
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
insert into control2 select @BatchID,@MemIdFetch

Fetch CursorABC into @MemIdFetch
END
```

Hope it helps